# Two Applications of Schwarz Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am hoping someone can clarify the application of the Schwarz inequality I have found in the following two situations.

$\textbf{1)}$ Consider the function in $L_2[0,1]$
$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^txds\right)^2dt$$
By the Schwarz inequality, we have that
$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^txds\right)^2dt\le\int_0^1\left(\underbrace{\int_0^t 1^2ds}_{=t}\underbrace{\int_0^tx^2ds}_{=||x||^2}\right)dt=\left[\frac{1}{2}t^2||x||^2\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{2}||x||^2$$

Fine, I think I can follow. I'm no too familiar enough to know if this is correct but I can at least follow the logic.

$\textbf{2)}$ Now consider the function in $L_2[0,1]$
$$\int_0^1\left|\int_0^tx-yds\int_0^tx+yds\right|dt$$
Again by Schwarz inequality, we have that
$$\int_0^1\left|\int_0^tx-yds\int_0^tx+yds\right|dt\le\int_0^1\sqrt{\int_0^1 1^2ds\int_0^1|x-y|^2ds}\sqrt{\int_0^1 1^2\int_0^1|x+y|^2ds}dt=||x-y||\cdot||x+y||$$

I guess specifically, why in this case did the integrals change from $\int_0^t$ to $\int_0^1$, thus just becoming $1$'s and effectively cancelling vs $t$'s which we needed to then integrate again? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer the question **2** (I do not see any specific question in **1**). The point here is that $$\begin{split} \left| \int_0^t (x(s) - y(s)) \, ds \right| \le \int_0^t |x(s) - y(s)| \, ds & \le \int_0^t |x(s) - y(s)| \, ds + \underbrace{\int_t^1 |x(s) - y(s)| \, ds}_{\ge 0} \\ & = \int_0^1 |x(s) - y(s)| \, ds \end{split}$$and then you apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you. No, as long as 1 is correct there is no real question, I just wanted to know the difference and it seems clear from your response.